# ListView not working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-arrayadapter

Working in a group to make an android app, currently I just need to create an Activity consisting of a ListView that displays several selectables (adapted from a String Array) -- eventually the ListView will take an array of objects that we're making, and depending on what objects are available on our server at the time, this array of objects is going to change (and thus, the entries of the ListView will change).
BUT FOR NOW, I just need to get it working with an array of strings.

So, here's my activity's xml, and java main.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/gamesListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:entries="@+id/gamesList"

    >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp" 
        android:text="Create"
        android:id="@+id/bCreate"
    />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:id="@+id/bRefresh"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
package com.youcanthide.android.gamespage;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button create, refresh; //browse
String gamesList[] = {"game1", "game2", "game3"};

//Game [] games; **********//the array of available games to populate the SlideView

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreate);
    refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRefresh);

    ListView games = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gamesListView);

    //Will have to remake adapter for Game objects
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, gamesList);
    games.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I've been trying to follow api and simple tutorials but I still cant figure out why it's breaking.
There's no error messages in eclipse, but when I run the emulator for the activity it gives me the "Unfortunately (projectname) has stopped".
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what is the problem you are having? Is it crashing? If so, please post logcat. If you are getting that message, then there are messages in the logcat of Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your XML:

```
 android:entries="@+id/gamesList"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ids in your ListView.
Delete one.

```
 ListView games = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gamesListView);
```

In you xml  delete `android:entries="@+id/gamesList"`.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/gamesListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"

    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you have to require this line XML file.

```
android:entries="@+id/gamesList"
```

Remove this line from xml and try this.

If you find any trouble then let me know.